# Why does datetime on x-axis change after datetime format is set?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime

After datetime format is set in python, datetime on x-axis is changed.

```
lgt_num = lgts.groupby(lgts['DateTime'].dt.floor('30min')).size()
ldates = lgt_num.index
lnum = lgt_num.to_numpy()
ax = lgt_num.plot(ylabel='#', color='k', figsize=(24,8))
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

[image: Describe data]
[image: normal result]

when I add code below:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y.%m.%d.%R')
```

[image: Changed result]

Values on x-axis is changed.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. The format of the xtick labels has changed because you changed them with `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y.%m.%d.%R')`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney For example, '08-09 00' at 5th major tick change to '22.08.08.15:00'. I just try to change the 'FORMAT', but the value is also changed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't know what %R is. It is not one of the strftime or strptime format codes, as shown in [python datetime docs Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). Maybe you want %H for hour or %H:%M.

Comment: @Joao_PS Your comment mean that x-value convert from datetime to string format. Right? But, I want to deal with x-values as datetime. I think x-values as string is hard to control of its spacing

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney '%R' is identical to '%H:%M:%S' as I know.

Comment: I'd still try with `%H:%M` just to verify. Since there's no complete [mre] with data as formatted text. That's not way to test.

Comment: One is in local time, and the other in UTC. You are using a pandas locator with a Matplotlib formatter, so you will likely have problems.

Comment: @JodyKlymak oh....you're right. I change mpl.rcParams['timezone'] to the local timezone, then it works. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Note that DateFormatter also takes a tz argument